# What are the costs associated with having an Azure VM image?

Tags: azure

Azure images does not seem to be a category in the Azure pricing calculator.

Is there a cost for storing VM images on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Look here for details on [Managed Images of a generalized VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/managed-disks/) for pricing.

If you want to store them as unmanaged disks (i.e. manage/maintain them yourself) then you can use a storage account and look at pricing information [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/page-blobs/).

If you are talking about container images, you can look [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/container-registry/).